# Visual Studio 2012 Feature Deploying with two servers

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

We have a two servers on farm. We issue using Visual Studio's "deploy" action where it can't install the feature because it couldn't be found :

Error 1 Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': 
Feature with Id 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope.

It seems like Visual Studio will only deploy to one server, and we've evidenced that with a project that just had a package and the package only deployed files to the server with the URL. But it doen's worked for us, too.

Does anyone have any idea on what we can do to get the VS 2012 deploying to work when you have two servers for SharePoint 2013?

Comment: When we deploy package, feature can be activated from GUI, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I am having the same issue and I am trying to find a solution for it.